# How to debug OnModelCreating Context Load as it is taking more time to load

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this function

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RecordHistoryMap());
}
```

and

```
public RecordHistoryMap()
{
    this.MapProperties();
    this.MapTableAndColumns();
}
```

RecordHistory table contains around 1.1 million rows and the context of this table is being queried whenever required.

**Monitoring tool is showing query "select top[?] * from RecordHistory" is taking time more than threshold value.**

Can I know why this context loading is taking time. How I can debug this